# Launch an mobile app on emulator using appium

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I wanted to launch my app in genemotion using Appium - Java.

I can launch the app on real device, But I feel its better to use Emulators instead of real devices. How I can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a Virtual Emulator on Genemotion, make it up and running. Then open your terminal and type:
adb devices

It will show, 
List of devices attached, make sure that new virtual device is running on some port. ie : 192.168.56.101:5555   device

Now use below use desired capabilities as below :

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

```
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Name of the Emulator");

    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

It will launch the apk in genemotion.